Friends release a demon in a party and one of them is possessed
It's a horror movie thats starts off with this girl and she goes to her guy friends house where they are having like a small graduation party? Or a birthday party, I don't remember. 
It's only a few friends like 6 of them. Anyway so they start drinking. The main character doesn't really want to drink. And then one of the guys has regular playing cards which he uses to do a magic trick and then they play like the Ouija board on them. Anyway they end up releasing a demon and it possesses one of the girls there and she starts to kill them after they play strip poker. The main character is asked to strip some clothes off and she doesn't want to and then after they kind of take her shirt it's revealed that she has bruises all over her body. And I remember one guy dies in the hot tub, and one of the girls in the bathroom - she cuts her collar bone with a razor. 
The way it ends is like the beginning - like it's going to repeat itself again. 
Extra details:

I watched it this year 2017. 
I believe it was filmed in maybe 2012-2017.
It's a US film in English.


Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Indeed, the film's country\language and its approximate year of release (or at least when you watched it) would be greatly appreciated... I'm pretty sure I know what this is, but those details would really help me out.

I watched it this year 2017. I believe it was filmed like maybe 2012-2017 ..it's a U.S film. In English.

@KarlaLoaiza Thanks, that really does help. Possible match below.

Sounds like Nocturne from 2016.

A girl running from her past is forced to confront her future when her friends perform an impromptu seance. Dirty secrets are revealed and an uninvited guest joins the party.

It contains all the scenes you mentioned: The possession, the strip poker, the guy dying in a hot tub and the girl cutting her colar bone - which you can see in the trailer around 1:28:




Omgassshh! Yay thank you!! I've been looking for it for a few months! Idk why i couldn't find! Thanks you are awesome!:)

The film sounds like the movie Ouija (2014) staring Olivia Cooke, but the synopsis doesn't mention anything about a party, but there is a wake.


Debbie Galardi recalls playing Ouija with her best friend Laine Morris
  as children. In present day, Debbie throws her Ouija board into the
  fire, burning it. Debbie implies to Laine that something strange
  happened with the Ouija board. After Laine leaves, the Ouija board
  reappears in Debbie's bedroom. Debbie becomes possessed and hangs
  herself. Laine attends Debbie's wake with her boyfriend Trevor,
  younger sister Sarah, friend Isabelle, and Debbie's boyfriend Pete.
  The five friends meet at Debbie's house and use her Ouija board to try
  communicating with her. Strange things happen, and a presence smashes
  Pete's head into a mirror. Later, the friends start finding the phrase
  "hi friend" (a message communicated during the Ouija board session)
  written in different places, like Isabelle's car window, a tunnel
  wall, Pete's desk, and Laine's computer. Thinking Deb is trying to
  communicate with them, the group has another Ouija session. They then
  discover that they are actually in contact not with Debbie but with a
  spirit calling itself "DZ." Laine sees the image of a little girl with
  her mouth sewn shut. The girl warns them to run because her mother is
  coming. Laine sees an old woman, and everyone flees. Laine later
  learns that Deb found the Ouija board in her attic and played alone.
The paranormal activity stops. Later, Laine finds that the planchette
  has mysteriously appeared back at her home in her bedroom, and as she
  sees through the planchette the film ends.
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouija_(2014_film)


No its not that one..there is no ouija board involved.. They play it with playing cards :/ thank you for trying. :)
